# Ubuntu 12.04 - Multimonitor - Office Use - Update AMD drivers?

Tags: 12.04, ati, 64-bit, multiple-monitors, fglrx

I am on a triple monitor 12.04.2 64-bit (and will stay till the next LTS). I have an ATI 5850 with the AMD catalyst drivers installed (fglrx), version 12.10. I do not play games. The only thing I require is a smooth(er) multi monitor experience.

Should I update to the newest 13.1 AMD drivers? Are there any changes to see for someone not playing games?

Is the multimonitor experience better in 12.10 or 13.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about multimonitor but if you want to update your catalyst drivers I would suggest that you use the repository method instead of the amd-installer one.

Specifically:

1) remove the ubuntu fglrx which are currently installed:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge fglrx*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and reboot.

2) Add the xorg-edgers ppa and install the latest drivers catalyst 13.2 (beta7):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

and reboot.

If you are on a true 12.04.2 ubuntu installation and thus running the Quantal kernel and xorg you can leave the ppa in your system and from now on the driver will update it self automatically.
If you are using the precise kernel 3.2.xx  you should remove the ppa before the final reboot because it will break your system during the next apt-get upgrade.

To do that simply give the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

you can add the repository back again the next time you'd like to update your drivers.

Comment: Why do you recommend the PPA and not the AMD installer? I always thought the PPA is more experimental than the official installer. Also it seems that the latest fglrx for 12.04.2 in the PPA is 12.12 not 13.1.

Comment: Because in linux it's always the best practice to not by-pass the system's package management. 
Nope it is 13.2 (beta7) ..the latest available by amd. I'm also on ubuntu 12.04.2 and I've installed it the same way I've described above. I was too a bit confused in the begining about the naming of the packages in the repo but as it turns out it is somekind of ubuntu specific version format.